# Web API2 How to log user actions with friendly names with an Annotation

Tags: c#, logging, asp.net-web-api

I'm working on a greenfield Web API and need to log users' actions in a friendly way. I can see its easy to gather the logged in user, the controller, the action, and parameters like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12300458/web-api-audit-logging/12300537)
What I am looking for is away to give human readable friendly messages like:

- "Paul Logged in" + timestamp
- "Paul Created a new product (*some product metadata*)" + timestamp
- "Paul Deleted Product xyz" + timestamp

I could adapt the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15363721/audit-logging-using-asp-net-mvc-4-actionfilter) and then use a lookup table on the controller and action to translate to my human readable string with some token replacements but I can see that being a maintenance overhead when new actions are added. It also means a developer might forget to put the call in and we miss auditing.

Is there a way I can use an **annotation** on the action to specify what my human readable log message will be? (possibly with tokens)
Has anybody done this in a generic manner without the code becoming totally custom to that application?

Answer (score 1):

I would look into an [Aspect oriented programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) framework to cross cut your application in a way that's maintainable. Having a strong typed annotation on every action specific to a logging mechanism will be readable and maintainable provided you are happy that to add a the logging capability, you will require a re-compilation. You could switch these on or off using a config setting easily.

I have used and would recommend PostSharp here, its awesome and free (for basic aspects).

A good example is:

http://doc.postsharp.net/example-trace

I have implemented a modified version of this with log4net and it works really well in a production environment.

Generally speaking i am not a fan of AOP as its surprise factor can be disconcerting, but in cases like this the maintenance overhead reduction is worth the trade off.

Answer (score 1):

I think that trying to accomplish this at the UI layer is the wrong place.  If I hit the url `foo.com/product/delete/1` does that mean that I deleted the product?  I would say no.

- What happens if that user didn't have permission?
- What happens if the product didn't exist?
- What happens if the product failed to delete?

I think the correct place to do this kind of auditing is at the repo layer of your code.  Have a method something like this:

```
public void DeleteProduct(int productID, string username) {
   _db.Products.Delete(productID); //pseudo code
   _auditService.AddAuditRecord($"Product ID {productID} was deleted by {username}");
}
```

This way, you only audit the data change if it was successful.

Comment: Some good points to consider @jhilden. The benefit of logging in the API layer as I see it would be if we had a requirement to audit if a user tries to do something they're not authorized to.